# Formatting input while values are typed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to format the values typed by the user in realtime, I'm doing this for some data types but the only one that I cannot make it work is with currency (number). Based on my other data types I'm trying to solve it with the following code:

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2).toLocaleString() " />

<input type="number" onkeypress="something(this.value);" />

function something(val) {
    return parseFloat(val).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
}
```

```js
function something(val) {
  return parseFloat(val).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="number" onkeypress="return parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2).toLocaleString() " />

<input type="number" onkeypress="something(this.value);" />
```

What I'm trying to is that for example: if my user is trying to type 25999.84125 change the input value to 25999.84 but, any of my code examples are working.

How can I solve this? I'll prefer to keep the event + function inside the input tag (example 1) but if the solution is writing a custom function it's okay. Also I'm open to use Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using changing the value real-time, don't return the data in the function, just set the value to the input !
Also you cannot do it exactly real-time with JS, you need to use onChange function like this:

```js
function something(val, input) {
    document.getElementById(`input${input}`).value = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="number" onChange="something(this.value, 1);" />

<input id="input2" type="number" onChange="something(this.value, 2);" />
```

finally, if you want to do it exactly real time, use Vue js